# Executing ADB commands while running scrcpy

Tags: adb, scrcpy

I am using the program [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) in order for me to control my Android phone from my PC.

It all works just fine with showing the Android screen, but I want to open an app from within the scrcpy console box.

[image]

I have not seen anything on Github about a feature like this - just the ability to add or remove an app.

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open up a new command prompt window and issue whatever adb commands you want. They would work.

You can also put scrcpy in background if you want to use the same command prompt window to do something else there. Head over to [Superuser](https://superuser.com/a/591084) to know more about this.

Comment: Although you do need to use the **adb.exe thats inside the scrcpy directory** to send the commands with. If you do not use that and use another installed adb.exe then it will disconnect scrcpy.

Comment: or even more better, delete the adb.exe that comes bundled with scrcpy

Comment: The recommended way to handle the ADB problem is creating a system environment variable called `ADB` which contains the path to the `adb.exe` to be used (e.g. from an Android ADK installed). Then scrcpy always uses this version and ignores the version that is shipped with scrcpy.